# Recreate directory structure and copy newest file

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have 100+ sub-directories all under the same folder that I'm looking to copy the newest file to backup location with the directory structure intact.

```
\data\sub1\newest.file -> \backup\sub1\newest.file
\data\sub1\older.file1.ignore
\data\sub1\older.file2.ignore
\data\sub2\newest.file -> \backup\sub2\newest.file
\data\sub2\older.file1.ignore
etc....
```

Here's what I have so far, and i can't seem to piece it together.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@echo off

set source="c:\data"

set dest="n:\backup"

if not exist %dest% md %dest%

cd /d %source%

for /d  %%x in ("%source%"/*.*) do (

if not exist "%dest%\%%x" md "%dest%\%%x"

FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR *.* /A-D /B /O-D') DO COPY %%I "%DEST%\%%X" & @ECHO %%I     COPIED TO "%DEST%\%%X"

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do this with [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) if I were you, because this will most likely be a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Windows' built-in `xcopy` program provides a flag to include empty directories.

```
C:\>xcopy "%source%" "%dest%" /E
```

But, it sounds like you may want to only copy newer/missing files. If that is the case, then @Marged has it right. You should use `robocopy`.

```
C:\>robocopy "%source%" "%dest%" /E
```

Check out `robocopy /?` for all the details and additional commands.

Answer (score 0):

The metavariable `%%x` in your `for` statement is **CaSe-SeNsItIvE** so you must use `%%x` throughout the loop, but you are using `%%X` in the `copy` statement.

Since you only want to copy the first file, you should append `&goto alabelotsideoftheforloop` which terminates the `for..x..` after the first file has been copied.